# linux logrotate, rotate file with underscore

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel, logrotate, log-rotation

I have a logrotate configuration which is given below.

```
/var/log/Test.log {
    size 50k
    missingok
    rotate 10
    notifempty
    create 0640 root root
}
```

The file is rotating successfully once it reached the size of 50kb in the below format

```
Test.log.1
Test.log.2
Test.log.3
```

What I can do if I want to rotate files in the below format

```
Test_1.log
Test_2.log
Test_3.log
```

Comment: Did you try the `extension` directive? As I understand it, with `extension log`, you'd end up with `Test.1.log`. I don't think your exact format is possible directly, but maybe with a `postrotate` script?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I don't have much knowledge about logrotate can you please guide me on what should I do for 'extension log'.

Comment: I know only what I read in the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/logrotate.8.html#CONFIGURATION_FILE_DIRECTIVES) about that directive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,it should help you.

```
/var/log/Test.log {
...

postrotate 
    /usr/bin/mv Test.log.1 Test_1.log
    ... 
endscript
}
```

Comment: This will not help as it has hardcoded values Test.log.1 Test_1.log

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the problem here is that `logrotate` uses these filename extensions to keep track of its rotations. So if you have `x.log`, it inherently needs a predictable, sequential extension to keep track of what is what; i.e. `x.log.1` is the first rotation, `x.log.2` is the second, etc.

By renaming the file like that, you're moving the extension to the middle of the file and subsequently leaving each file with the *same* extension: `.log`. So as far as logrotate is concerned, it will think those are all unrelated files, not rotations of a previous log.

E.g., if you rename `Test.log.1` to `Test_1.log`, and leave that file in the same folder, `logrotate` won't know that it's a rotation of `Test.log` and create a new `Test.log.1` upon next rotation. And so on, and so on.

So the short answer is no, there is no `logrotate` directive that will rename a file like you want. You will have to create this functionality yourself using a `postrotate` script, and you will also have to (at some point) move these files out of the `var/log/` directory once they're renamed, using either said `postrotate` script or the `olddir` directive.

The `dateext` directive might also be useful, as in my opinion date extensions are typically more user-friendly than numerical ones.